# TeamCity Do not trigger for a particular user

Tags: triggers, teamcity

I'd like to know if there is a way to disable the trigger for a particular user.
At the beggining of my build step I commit a versioning file and I dont want this commit to trigger another build.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the username in the VCS trigger rule for your build configuration, such as "-user=VCS_username". The trigger rules are pretty flexible. I've even used them to conditionally trigger some dependent builds based on whether I use a certain keyword on a commit message. You can see more in depth doc in the [TeamCity documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+VCS+Triggers).